# Is "zu" used to describe purpose?

Tags: preposition, noun

I saw the following sentence in a dialogue:

> Wir sind zum Besuch hier

Is this a common construction to describe one's purpose of being somewhere, or doing something? Is there a formal name for this construction? Can you do this with any noun, and is it used in this format?

> Ich bin zum (Noun) hier?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should be ***zu*** Besuch, which is more of a fixed expression.

Otherwise, yes it can be used with many nouns to express a purpose.
***Zum*** (zu dem) and ***zur*** (zu der) are contractions that are used in conjunction with words of their respective genus (*zum:* masculine, neutral; *zur:* feminine).

Nominalized verbs (*Putzen, Arbeiten*) always have a neutral genus and are, hence, used with ***zum*** (***zum*** Putzen, **zum** Arbeiten). In contrast, *Arbeit* (***die*** Arbeit) is used with ***zur*** (***zur*** Arbeit) because it is feminine.
Words nominalized with *-ung* are feminine, and thus also require **zur**.

> Ich bin **zum** Arbeiten hier.
>   (zum Putzen, zum Abholen, zum Aufräumen, zum Grillen)
>
> Ich bin **zur** Arbeit hier.
>   (zur Erholung, zur Weiterbildung, zur Gerichtsverhandlung, zur Wohnungsendabnahme, zur Hochzeit, zur Geburtstagsfeier)